# how to have customisable wamp url

Tags: wordpress, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress"
ServerName yg8i.tk
ServerAlias www.yg8i.tk
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory  "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted        
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but this will only give them my wordpress website and also if someone types  www.yg8i.tk/whatever they will have access to my files.
and i also want to have custom urls so for example i would like to type www.yg8i.tk/login to login to my wordpress site so my solution was

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress\wp-login.php"
ServerName yg8i.tk\login
ServerAlias www.yg8i.tk\login
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
<Directory  "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress\wp-login.php">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted        
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but it does not work i really need ur help.

> I Hope You Help And Thank You In Advance.

Comment: This is not the way WordPress or Apache Virtual Hosts work. If you want to change the way WordPress works, try the [WordPress website re Force Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-login/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly my question is not about wordpress my question is about how to make customisable urls that link to a specific file and what is above is only but an example > Sorry for the confusion! and i think this is exactly what Apache Virtual Hosts is supposed to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you check your wamp forum messages

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry can you come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to this, `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory...` can only have a directory as their value.

You can use the DocumentIndex to cause any other script to be launches

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress"
ServerName yg8i.tk\login
ServerAlias www.yg8i.tk\login
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DocumentIndex wp-login.php
<Directory  "C:\wamp\www\TEST1\wordpress">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted        
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```